# C++: Macro to declare for initialized multi-dim vector?

Tags: c++, macros

One way to initialize a multi-dimensional vector is:

```
vector<vector<... vector<int> > >
  v(D1, vector<vector... <int> >
   (D2, vector<...vector<int>>
    ...
   (DN-1, vector<int>(DN, X))...);
```

(dots not part of code)

will initialize a D1 x D2 x ... x DN vector with the value X.

Is it possible to wrap this in a macro somehow so that I can say:

```
DECL_VECTOR(v, X, D1, D2, ..., DN);
```

How would you define DECL_VECTOR ?

**Note:** This is not for production code of course, it's a shorthand macro for a programming competition template.

Comment: varient macros, ..., are possible.  Typedefs are the usual way to handle this sort of thing though...

Comment: On a completely unrelated note, using a `vector<vector<T>>` as a multidimensional array in performance critical code is a really bad idea. If the code is not performance sensitive then it's a moot point onbviously.

Comment: Why is vector<Vector<T>> bad idea in performance critical code ?

Comment: @VishnuPedireddi: more memory accesses per element access.

Comment: You might go with an n-dimension vector wrapper that stores a 1D vector.

Comment: a 2D array lookup is no more slow than a 1D array lookup.  A 2D vector lookup, as it is a jagged array, takes much, much more overhead to get into the final value.  Don't code for performance though until you need to code for performance.

Comment: If that's an option, boost::multi_array is your friend. Seriously. (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/multi_array/doc/index.html)

Comment: @VishnuPedireddi: The most obvious is frequent dynamic memory allocation.  You can get around this if the size of the matrix is known in advance though by calling `reserve()`.  The largest problem is that the data will not be contiguous in memory, so you end up flushing the cache often when iterating through it whereas, with an array, you would end up utilizing the cache very nicely..

Comment: Not only is frequent allocation a problem, but indirection is a problem.  If you have a vectors nested N-deep, it requires N indirections through pointers to find an element.  In performance critical code, that can add up very, very fast, especially if you have large data that may cause a read from memory for each level of indirection.

Comment: If you know the dimensions at compile time, you can define a recursive template to create a class that will dimensionalize the vector of vectors for you in its constructor.